# VLC Playlist with Folders fails

Tags: command-line, vlc-media-player, shortcuts, playlists

I have a playlist that consists of two folders.
I have random and repeat active on VLC 2.2.4

When I click to play the playlist it expands one folder only - and once it gets to folder two it expands this one too.

I would like it to expand both folders content at once so that the random function choose from all the files from the start - and not only from the moment it reaches folder #2 on the list. Any suggestions?

Playlist code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<playlist xmlns="http://xspf.org/ns/0/" xmlns:vlc="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/ns/0/" version="1">
<title>Playlist</title>
<trackList>
    <track>
        <location>file:///C:/Users/JP/Desktop/Bastianvideo/English</location>
        <extension application="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/0">
            <vlc:id>0</vlc:id>
        </extension>
    </track>
    <track>
        <location>file:///C:/Users/JP/Desktop/Bastianvideo/Danish</location>
        <extension application="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/0">
            <vlc:id>1</vlc:id>
        </extension>
    </track>
</trackList>
<extension application="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/0">
        <vlc:item tid="0"/>
        <vlc:item tid="1"/>
</extension>
</playlist>
```

I am not picky about the solution - command-line / bat file is fine too. Worked a bit with this line:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe"  -LZ E:\music
```

However, this takes only one folder, and so far it has not worked for me.
Using a windows shortcut should also be an option - but again have only found limited info on how to send arguments here.

Comment: Looks like the only way is to expand each folder manually and save the Playlist (containing individual file paths). But if you add more mp3 files later, the playlist need to be regenerated. https://askubuntu.com/questions/774115/open-multiple-directories-with-vlc-in-command-line / https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=103925

Comment: According to the askubuntu comments it was solved with /* however, I cannot seem to make that argument in windows - any ideas`?

Comment: Prior to posting I tested it (in Windows) but doesn't work.