# The status of folders and metadata in VLC

Tags: search, vlc-media-player, metadata, recursive

When using `Random` in VLC, the probability of a folder being played is equal to that of a root file. In other words, the sampling is stratified by the top folder in the root. However, once a folder is expanded, the files are added to the population.

One could ask, if it is possible to set VLC to ignore the folder hierarchies and just process each files as such. This has been asked before, but is still unanswered ([VLC Playlist with Folders fails](https://superuser.com/questions/1100769/vlc-playlist-with-folders-fails)).

Continuing on the status of folders in the VLC playlist: the folders contain files with metadata. However, the search function does not appear to reach inside folders. This seems like a bug too me.

Should I report this as a bug to the VLC community, or is there some way around the second class status of folder contents?

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what is that you are trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 1):

advanced settings > input > access-module > file > behavior > expand

works for me

Comment: Already set to expand.